# Will my script send to many requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, ddos

I currently have a script that scrapes data from a website by visiting a url and then scraping a certain piece of information. My only concern is that since there is roughly 30,000 pages to scrape that it might appear to the server as a DDoS attack? On top of this I was recommended to use Typhoeus gem for ruby to complete them all basically simultaneously. So I was just wondering if this should be alright?

Comment: Hmmm, depends on how often you "scrap" data from that website :)

Comment: Technically it wouldn't be a DDOS attack as the first D stands for distributed - meaning the requests come from a number of machines.  Yours would all come from the same host, which i would think would be less likely to trigger an alert.  However, the frequency of requests might be an issue, especially if typhoeus is sending loads at once in parallel threads (or whatever it does).  You might be better off not using typhoeus if you're worrying about triggering an alarm, and instead just leave your script to run overnight.

Comment: Sometimes it might help if you add just a little `sleep` after certain amount of requests.

Comment: @MaxWilliams yea thats what I was thinking. I reckon the best method would be to only scrape each show only if a user has followed that show so it would get maybe 200 per scrape (once a day) instead of 30k. Does this sound a lot safer? and i wouldn't use typheous for this as 200 would only take a couple of mins.

Comment: Is this something you're going to be doing on an ongoing basis?  I assumed it was a one-off data collection exercise.  I assume there's no API?  That would obviously be much cleaner.  Long-term scraping is very prone to error as it could be broken any time they update the website: it's a maintenance pita.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I am new to rails and programming and i'm just trying to learn how everything works. I dont really expect this to be a long lasting project but I want to see the app work for a while at least.

Comment: Cool.  Data scraping is a good exercise :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A DDoS attack cant be performed by a single machine because DDoS means **Distributed** Denial of Service. So in the worst case it can be recognised as a DoS attack which isn't likely unless your using a huge amount of threads to perform page calls.

A single thread used by your bot isn't even a problem to a default configured apache because the connections per host are limited to 10 I think. By using 1 thread youre only having one connection established after another so you never even reach the limitation for one host. A normal browser may establishes more connections by default by downloading the assets of the webpage after it receiverd the html file. To sum it up: nope you dont seem to be an attacker by the view of the webserver admin.

Comment: Your welcome... if your interested in how D(D)oS attacks against webservers even work you can lookup these keywords for common scenarois: SYN-Flood, UDP amplification attacks, slow read attack (GET), slow write attack (POST).